# group-by in group-by from xml to xslt

Tags: xml, excel, xslt

0
I have a xml like this

```
<rows>
    <row type="first" month="jan" value="3"/>
    <row type="first" month="feb" value="4"/>
    <row type="first" month="march" value="32"/>
    <row type="second" month="jan" value="5"/>
    <row type="second" month="march" value="6"/>
</rows>
```

I convert it with xslt to an excel file and I want my excel file to look like this:

```
       jan  feb march
first   3   4   32
second  5       6
```

I thought to do that with a group-by in a group-by, but it doesn't work. I have read something like using templates, but I have no experience with xslt and I don't know how to start.

can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want csv output which can be imported by Excel and converted to either Excel format (.xls or .xlsx). If this is what you want then this XSLT 2.0 stylesheet ...

### CSV Output

```
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="rows">
  <xsl:text>type,</xsl:text>
  <xsl:variable name="months" as="xs:string*" select="fn:distinct-values( row/@month)" />
  <xsl:value-of select="$months" separator="," />
  <xsl:text>&#x0A;&#x0D;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="@type">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(current-grouping-key(),',')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="
         for $m in $months return
           concat( current-group()[@month eq $m]/@value,'')"
         separator="," />
  <xsl:value-of select="'&#x0A;&#x0D;'" />
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

... when applied to this input document ...

```
<rows>
    <row type="first" month="jan" value="3"/>
    <row type="first" month="feb" value="4"/>
    <row type="first" month="march" value="32"/>
    <row type="second" month="jan" value="5"/>
    <row type="second" month="march" value="6"/>
</rows>
```

... will yield this csv file, which can be imported into MS Excel ...

```
type,jan,feb,march
first,3,4,32
second,5,,6
```

### Direct XLSX Transformation?

It is possible to transform to xlsx, with the aide of a zip program, because xlsx is just a zip file containing xml files. Let us know if this is what you want instead.

### About Getting Started

In relation to your more general question about how to get started with XSLT, I suggest that you buy and read a book. If you search StackOverflow, there are already a few questions asking for book recommendations, with plenty of answers.